# Ubuntu, How to prevent listing sub-directory if parent-directory is protected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, user-management, chmod

I remember last time when I am on some Linux OS ( cannot remember ), when I change the mod of a directory to 711, that folder together with all of its sub-directories cannot be listed (ls -al) by any other user different from the owner.

However my Ubuntu 12.04 does not behave like that. Is there any setting available to set this up ?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the permissions of a directory to `711` will only prevent that one directory's contents from being listed. If you want the same to apply to subdirectories, you'd have to change the permissions of the subdirectories, too. Here is a command to help you:

```
find /dir -type d -exec chmod 711 {} +
```

You'd still have to do it for any newly created directories, though.